# Tomcat 6.x web.xml default and custom servlet routing

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

I have two servlets defined in the web.xml file, namely the default2 and myservlet. The default2 servlet is used to map the static files like the javascript and css. The myservlet is used for getting dynamic content.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:my-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The servlet mapping is defined as follows

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When i try to access any files under /resources, i get a 404. Any ideas why this config is not working or change this config to make it work.

Comment: What does Tomcat error say? Also, why are both servlet loaded with same value `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>`?

Comment: There is no tomcat error on startup. When we access any files under /resources it gives a file not found error.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat's default servlet before 6.0.30 actually serves a static resource identified by `HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo()`, so that `/style.css` will be returned when `/resources/style.css` is requested.

Tomcat's behavior has changed from version 6.0.30 onwards. So the original configuration from the question works in newer versions of Tomcat. See "[50026](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50026): Add support for mapping the default servlet to URLs other than /. (timw)" in the [changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_6.0.30_%28jfclere%29/Catalina).

Jetty's default servlet uses a full path.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine. Are those files *in real* also located in the `/resources` folder?

Comment: The exception tells it is not. Are they accessible by the same URL when you remove the both servlets? If still not, then URL used and/or actual location is plain wrong (or you have a `Filter` listening on `/*` which is badly written and is thus disturbing everything).

Answer (score 0):

Your web.xml looks correct (except I would change your `<load-on-startup>` constants).
Make sure that your `/resources` exists and is a publicly visible folder in your project path and not under /WEB-INF folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `url-pattern` for `myservlet` to `/`, and optionally adding `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` ([see here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler)) to your Spring configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Removed wrong portion of the answer as per @BalusC comment.

Set a break point in your servlet and perform a debug session. Look for the path that your servlet is picking up these files at. Make sure they match the location

Comment: Wrong, the servletcontainer will match the *most specific* servlet url pattern. Probably you're confusing it with the behaviour of filters.

Comment: Yeah you are write. I wasn't thinking. 
Still setting a breakpoint in the servlet will help determine where the application is looking for a file.

Comment: I suggest to edit your post as you're getting negative score.